# How to access only cell value in python?

Tags: python, excel

I want to draw the cell itself, not the formula line in excel, how can I do this.

I want to take 18758,55 but python idle output is B2*5

my code is :

```
import openpyxl

book=openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")

sheet = book.active


b2 = sheet['B2']
b3 = sheet['B3']
b4 = sheet['B4']
b5 = sheet['B5']
b6 = sheet['B6']
b8 = sheet['B8']
i7 = sheet['I7']

sheet.cell(row=7, column=9).value = "=B2*5"

print(b8.value)


book.save('test.xlsx')
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify, is the issue the permission error in the screen shot, the output not matching, or not being able to access the value of a cell?

Comment: The output is B2*5 but i want to -> 187538,55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the calculation in Python instead of doing it in Excel, so that you are then just passing the value when you set the cell.

```
import openpyxl

book=openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")

sheet = book.active


b2 = sheet['B2']
b3 = sheet['B3']
b4 = sheet['B4']
b5 = sheet['B5']
b6 = sheet['B6']
b8 = sheet['B8']
i7 = sheet['I7']
print (i7)

value_to_add = b2.value * 5

sheet.cell(row=7, column=9).value = value_to_add


book.save('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I use this option.